# How to Read ndJSON file in Java

Tags: java, json, java-8, gson, ndjson

I am new to `ndJSON`. I have an `ndJSON` file with the following data:

```
{
   "Top-level":{
      "customer_no":"1",
      "created":"2019-03-27 14:24:54",
      "last_visited_day_time":null,
      "login":"roni_cost@example.com"
   },
   "profile":{
      "salutation":"Mr",
      "title":null,
      "company":null,
      "job_title":null,
      "first_name":"Veronica",
      "last_name":"Costello",
      "name_suffix":"NONE",
      "gender":"Female",
      "birthday":"1973-12-15",
      "email":"roni_cost@example.com",
      "next_birthday":"2022-12-15",
      "second_name":null
   },
   "phone":{
      "home_phone":null,
      "business_phone":null,
      "mobile_phone":null,
      "fax_number":null
   },
   "addresses":[
      {
         "address_id":"1",
         "title":"",
         "company":null,
         "salutation":null,
         "first_name":"Veronica",
         "last_name":"Costello",
         "second_name":null,
         "suffix":"NONE",
         "address_1":"6146 Honey Bluff Parkway",
         "address_2":"",
         "suite_no":"",
         "postal_box":"",
         "city":"Calder",
         "postal_code":"49628-7978",
         "country":"US",
         "state":"Michigan",
         "contact_phone":"(555) 229-3326"
      }
   ],
   "orders":{
      "placed_orders_count":2,
      "0":{
         "order_id":"000000001",
         "order_date":"2019-03-27 14:25:03"
      },
      "1":{
         "order_id":"000000002",
         "order_date":"2019-03-27 14:25:03"
      }
   },
   "customs":[
      
   ]
}
```

I want to read this file into my program and extract data from it.

Following is my code to read the file from my system and trying to write it in `CustomerDTO` object

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader("customer.json"));
customerFeedDTO = gson.fromJson(reader, CustomerFeedDTO.class);
```

But I am getting following exception:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 138 path $.profile
```

And my CustomerFeedDTO is:

```
public class CustomerFeedDTO {

    private ArrayList<?> topLevel;
    private ArrayList<?> profile;
    private ArrayList<?> phone;
    private ArrayList<?> addresses;
    private ArrayList<?> orders;
    private ArrayList<?> customs;

//Getters and setters
```

I am trying to map all the data from the `ndJSON` file into my `customerDTO` object

Comment: I'm not sure how DTO works, and haven't touched Gson in a while, but it looks like DTO is formatted with ArrayList for profile, and the JSON for profile you supplied is an object {}, which seems pretty similar to the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the given json, your model class should looks like below.

```
public class CustomerFeedDTO {

    private Map<String, ?> topLevel;
    private Map<String, ?> profile;
    private Map<String, ?> phone;
    private ArrayList<?> addresses;
    private Map<String, ?> orders;
    private ArrayList<?> customs;
}
```

topLevel, profile, phone, orders are objects, should be modeled as objects or map, not as list.

Comment: That is a good answer although the `topLevel` should be defined same as in the file i.e. "Top-level" to map it but since the, Java Variable naming rules does not allow hyphen between variable names, you must try changing the `Top-level` in the file as well.

Otherwise, it will give `null` result. So consider using same spelling of fields as they are in the Json file

Comment: Thanks @Eatsamulhaq.
I was getting the topLevel as null before but after changing it with right spelling, I was able to get its value.